# Struct array initialization without values

Tags: arrays, matlab, array-initialization

I have a structure

```
AStructX : 7x1 struct array with fields:
    field1
    field2
    field3
    field4
    field5
```

Now I want to generate an empty 1x7 that looks like the previous struct, but with empty values.

I tried
`AStructY = repmat(AStructX(1),1,7);` but the values of `AStructX` is copied.

I tried 
`AStructY = repmat(AStructX(1),1,0);` when I add values to it, it pass with MATLAB, but Coder generation fails with the following error message 
`??? Subscripting into an empty matrix is not supported.`

Comment: If it's not supported, don't do it. Instead of inserting the first element with `AStructY(1)=El` use `AStructY=El`

Comment: Is the `cell2struct` approach compatible with coder generation?  I'm not able to test.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html):

```
len = 7;
fn = fieldnames(AStructX)
AStructY = cell2struct(repmat({[]},numel(fn),len),fn)
```

That gives a `7x1 struct array` with the same fields, empty contents.  If you want a `1x7`, simply transpose the array (i.e. `AStructY = cell2struct(...).'`).

Comment: Right, there was a built in way.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make the following assumptions:
1. AStructX is 2-D.
2. You want the new structure to have the size `size(AStructX')`.
3. The field names are not fixed.

To do this, you first need the fieldnames, then create a new struct with empty cells as values:

```
names = fieldnames(AStructX)'; %'// row vector
len = length(names); %// number of fields
for i=1:len
  names{2,i} = cell(size(AStructX')); %'// the contents are empty
end
AStructY = struct( names{:} ); %// will take the names matrix columnwise
```

This will result in completely empty entries (`[]`), if you want to initialize the values to `0` instead, the line inside the loop becomes

```
  names{2,i} = num2cell(zeros(size(AStructX'))); %'// initialize values to 0
```

Comment: AStructX is a one dimension array of structs, the structs have the fields1-field5

Comment: That's a special case of 2-D with custom field names, it's just not allowed to have **more** than 2 dimensions. This will work in your example.

Comment: it gave me a struct of array elements though, with is closer to was I am trying to get

Comment: Really? It should make a struct array... Can you try with a 2-D array to see if that's the problem? I have a workaround for that problem, but it shouldn't be the reason... It did work when i tested it, what Matlab build do you use?

Comment: R2013a, I will retry it

Comment: it work great, but It doesnt behave like when creating an array with zeros?

Comment: That's intentional, you said empty, 0 is not empty :P if you want 0, replace `cell` with `num2cell(zeros` and add one `)` at the end of that line.

Comment: @aboody: I added the line in the answer above. Pick whichever version fits your needs best ;)